# SOAP Client extension for Firefox or Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, soap

is there a SOAP client extension for firefox or chrome?

I have a WSDL url, which I want to enter and then run some of the service methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this: https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/soa-client/
Works on firefox 26.

Answer (score 15):

This tool

Chrome Web Store - Wizdler

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb

was working even better than the soa-client. I mean I had some problems with soa-client when I tried to put some parameters on any call function.

Bye

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on a Chrome app called [Boomerang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah).

This app can be used to make both SOAP and REST api calls.

Comment: I suggest you start with boomerang, this one is very user friendly and very fast compared to other versions.